# Using std::string in c++ dll to then be used in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have created a dll, with a function like this

CFunc.h

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) void fillStr(char* retStr, int strlen);
```

CFunc.cpp

```
void fillStr(char* retStr, int strlen)
{
    //Option 1
    const char* retTemp = "abc";
    
    //Option 2
    string retString = "abc";
    const char* retTemp = retString.c_str();
    cout << "ret in dlb:" << retTemp << endl;
                    
    strcpy_s(retStr, strlen, retTemp);
}
```

Then in C# I have

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll")]
static extern string fillStr(StringBuilder str, int strLen);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2^31);

fillStr(sb, sb.Capacity);
string myString = sb.ToString();
```

When I use option 1, which is to directly create the const char*, the program works fine.
However, when I use a string, it crashes unexpectedly, with the exception "A heap has been corrupted". I have tried using memcpy and creating the string on the heap, to then delete later, but same error.

Comment: I don't think `strcpy_s` exists in C++. Have you tried `std::strncpy` or `retString.copy`? Keep in mind you may need to null-terminate `retStr` manually.

Comment: Don't think that's the issue, when using option 1 and `strcpy_s` it works fine.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Option 2 is the one that doesn't work, should've clarified.

Comment: Just to note, writing `2^31` in C# does not mean 2 to the power of 31, it means 2 xor 31, which is 29. Probably a lot less than you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake.
The C++ function is `void` while the C# code looks for a returned `string`.
Changing it to this

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll")]
static extern void fillStr(StringBuilder str, int strLen);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2^31);

fillStr(sb, sb.Capacity);
string myString = sb.ToString();
```

worked.